# Is it possible to save the NavBackStackEntry's ViewModels?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

I've been trying to create a custom saver for my app state in Jetpack Compose such:

> ```
> object MainAppSaver:Saver<AppState, Map<String, Any>>
> {
>
>      override fun restore(value: Map<String, Any>): AppState?
>   {
>      val snackBarHostState = value["snackBarHostState"] as SnackbarHostState
>      val navHostController = value["navHostController"] as NavHostController
>      val snackBarManage = value["snackBarManage"] as ManageSnackBar
>      val resources = value["resources"] as Resources
>      val coroutineScope = value["coroutineScope"] as CoroutineScope
>     return AppState(snackbarHostState = snackBarHostState, navHostController = navHostController, manageSnackBar = snackBarManage, resources = resources,
>  coroutineScope = coroutineScope)
>   }
>
>     override fun SaverScope.save(value: AppState): Map<String, Any>?
>   {
>       return mapOf(
>       "snackBarHostState" to value.snackbarHostState,
>       "navHostController" to value.navHostController,
>       "snackBarManage" to value.manageSnackBar,
>       "resources" to value.resources,
>       "coroutineScope" to value.coroutineScope)
>   }
> }
> ```

to be used for rememberSaveable{} that survives configuration changes.
After creating the saver, I created a composable called rememberState as follows:

```
@Composable
fun rememberState(snackBarHostState: SnackbarHostState = remember{ SnackbarHostState()}, navHostController: NavHostController = rememberNavController(), snackBarManage:ManageSnackBar = ManageSnackBar, resources: Resources = resources(), coroutineScope: CoroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()):AppState
 {
    return rememberSaveable(saver = MainAppSaver)
    {
      AppState(snackBarHostState, navHostController, snackBarManage, resources, coroutineScope)
    }
 }
```

I define AppState in a class

```
class AppState(val snackbarHostState: SnackbarHostState, val navHostController: NavHostController,
val manageSnackBar: ManageSnackBar, val resources: Resources, val coroutineScope: CoroutineScope)
 {
init
{
coroutineScope.launch()
    {
 manageSnackBar.snackBarFlow.collect()
        {
snackBar->
snackBar?.let()
            {
snackBarMessage ->
   val text = snackBarMessage.toMessage(resources)
   val actionText = when(snackBarMessage)
                {
     is SnackBarMessage.StringSnackBarAction -> snackBarMessage.actionText
     is SnackBarMessage.ResourceSnackBarAction -> snackBarMessage.actionText
                }
   val onClick = when(snackBarMessage)
                {
    is SnackBarMessage.StringSnackBarAction -> snackBarMessage.onClick
    is SnackBarMessage.ResourceSnackBarAction -> snackBarMessage.onClick
                }
   val snackBarResult = snackbarHostState.showSnackbar(message = text, actionLabel = actionText,
 duration = SnackbarDuration.Short)
 when(snackBarResult)
                {
   SnackbarResult.ActionPerformed -> if(onClick != null) onClick()
    SnackbarResult.Dismissed -> {}
                }
            }

        }
    }
  navHostController.addOnDestinationChangedListener()
    {
   _ ->
   manageSnackBar.clearMessages()
        }
    }
fun navigateTo(route:String)
  {
   navHostController.navigate(route)
      {
     launchSingleTop = true
    }
   }
 }

}
```

> 

In my main composable, I use rememberState:

```
 @Composable
  fun MainApp()
   {
 val appState = rememberState()
Scaffold(bottomBar =
        {
 BottomNavigationBar(navHostController = 
appState.navHostController, showBottomBar = showBottomBar, 
haptic = haptic,
 themeOption = selectedTheme, selectedItem = selectedItem)

 snackbarHost =
        {
 SnackbarHost(hostState = appState.snackbarHostState, 
 Modifier.padding(bottom = 20.dp),
 snackbar =
                    {
 snackData ->
 Snackbar(snackData, shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.medium,
 actionColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
  containerColor = containerColor, contentColor = contentColor)
                    })
            })
            {
 inner->
 Box(modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxSize()
                        .padding(inner))
                {
 AppNavigation(appState = appState, showBottomBar = 
  showBottomBar, haptic = haptic, themeOption = selectedTheme)
                }
            }
 }
```

This is my AppNavigation composable:

```
  @Composable
 fun AppNavigation(appState: AppState, 
showBottomBar:MutableState<Boolean>, haptic: HapticFeedback, 
themeOption: ThemeOption)
  {
    val startDestination = if(isUserLoggedIn()) 
    NavigateRoute.NotesScreen.route else 
    NavigateRoute.OnBoardingScreen.route
    NavHost(navController = appState.navHostController, 
    startDestination = startDestination)
    {
    // Composables
      }
  }
```

The issue, after creating the saver and rotating, the app crashes and throws

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: You cannot access the
> NavBackStackEntry's ViewModels after the NavBackStackEntry is
> destroyed.

How can I fix it? What I want is when rotating, the snackbar and navigation to retain their states. I would appreciate the reply.

What I expect is when the device is being rotating(activity is being destroyed and recreated), I expect the Snackbar and the navigation state to be retained. I am using Firebase for my database and storage, when the content has been added to the server, I expect the current screen(Add screen) to navigate back to the previous screen (list of contents) while popping the back stack. While it works on one orientation, it doesn't navigate when rotating.

Comment: A NavController you've created with `rememberNavController()` already saves and restores its own state across configuration changes and process death and recreation. What makes you think you need to manually save anything at all?

Comment: Because while a content is being added to Firebase and there is a rotation and TBD content has successfully been added to Firebase, it doesn't navigate, that's one. Two, when the snackbar is being shown and rotates occurs, it goes away. It doesn't retain it.

Comment: What does 'it doesn't navigate' mean? If you strip away all of the `Saver` stuff (which you absolutely can't use with NavController) and just use what is returned by `rememberNavController`, `navigate` is always going to work.

Comment: In my viewmodel, I pass a route:()-> Unit as parameter. If the content has been added, navigate back like this:
    suspend fun addContent(bodyContent: String?, route:()->Unit, context: Context)
{ viewModelScope.launch(){
        val isContentAdded = service.addContent( bodyContent)
  if(isContentAdded) route()} and in my composable: 
the route is defined as navHostController.navigateToAndPopUpBackStack(toRoute = navHostController.previousBackStackEntry?.destination?.route!!,
           fromRoute = navHostController.currentBackStackEntry?.destination?.route!!)}